# FT232RQ USB pins order confusion

Tags: pcb, usb, differential, ftdi

I am implementing a USB to UART conversion board with a FT232RQ. What confuses me is the fact that the USB_D+ and USB_D- pins of the package are sequenced in precisely the opposite order as they are on any USB connector.

What options do I have to properly route the USB traces? I have come up with the following but I am not really satisfied with any. On the other hand I am at most a beginner so your hints might help clarifying the issue.

1. use a through-hole USB connector and place the FT232RQ on the opposite side to the connector such that the traces go straight
2. use a SMD connector and place the FT232RQ on the opposite side, but route the traces through vias
3. place the components on the same side and do some crazy trace gymnastics (having to match their length).

Additionally, being a quad-flat package, there is no possibility of routing the USB traces "under" the package.

Is this even a "real" problem? The confusion might be fully due to my lack of experience in the field.

Thanks you!

Comment: Which USB connector? MicroUSB?

Comment: @Justme yes, microUSB it is

Comment: your concerns over matched length are probably overly cautious, as long as you route it differentially. USB is fairly tolerant. Some rooting length variance near the connection to the chip isn't going to make or break you.

Comment: @vicatcu I agree. I guess what really gets me more is the aesthetics of it, having to either cross the traces or route them around the connector instead of straight, generally speaking.

Comment: Found related https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/209282/268162 with another possible solution

Comment: This is only USB full speed, it won't be that critical, vias, flyover via a small series resistor, etc will work.