How to route USB signals to CP2102
For some reasons I don't understand, the CP2102's USB signals are reversed from most common USB connectors:

Of course I can place a couple of vias in order to jump on the other side and reach the pad. Since, usually, engineers don't make odd things unless there is a valid reason, I'm asking if am I missing anything or I only have to place pads to make a good routing here.

see also: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/209236/usb-signal-routing-swap-data-lines-using-vias

That's a 12Mbps USB FS. There is no need  for the chip developers to think about connector pinouts, as there are always connectors that don't match and connectors that do match, or in the case of Type-C, the other half will always be wrong anyway.
And some people will put the connector and chip on different sides of the PCB so it may require vias anyway, whether or not you need to swap the lane polarity while swapping the layers.
You could also start the routing from connector not towards the chip, but away from it, and go up or down under the connector to route away from the connector, and thus have an U-turn back to the chip, so the lane polarity will be correct.

@Justme wrote how you can easily solve the issue on your board.
Here's the reason why the pinout doesn't fit: These connectors are meant to be mounted on the bottom side of the board.
While the older USB standards don't force a defined orientation of the socket, there are several suggestions in the specifications implying that the USB micro-B connector should be mounted with the shorter side facing upward.
In this orientation the USB logo on the cable is facing upward and visible.
(See also: https://superuser.com/a/1584173/1795027)
If you check your devices you'll find many that adhere to this, but there is also a minority who do otherwise.
Here's a link to the web page of one USB socket producer who happens to have a nice visual display of the different versions of USB micro sockets:
https://gct.co/usb-connector/usb-orientations-and-mount-types
